# how to select a particular column in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

This is my query for selecting a column named 'course':

```
$query = "SELECT course from surprise WHERE diff_lvl = "'.$level.'" AND
          tot_days = "'.$time_day'" AND tot_time = "'.$time_tot.'" "; \\(it is basically single quote inside a double quotes)
```

But I am getting error as:

> syntax error, unexpected ''.$level.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\sup_logic.php.

What should I do to fix it?

Is there any way I can write a query to get the value of course column?

Comment: Your quotes are in the reverse. You opened a double quoted string `"SELECT..."` so move the single quote (which is part of the syntax around the `diff_lvl` value) _inside_ the double quotes. Looks like the same for `$time_tot`. --- `WHERE diff_lvl = '". $level ."' ...`

Comment: This looks like it could have been alleviated by using prepared statements instead of concatenated variables. But see also [When to use single quotes double quotes and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql/11321508#11321508) for several examples of what a string with variables like this in SQL could be expressed as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
$query = "SELECT course from surprise WHERE diff_lvl = '$level' AND tot_days = '$time_day' AND tot_time = '$time_tot'";
```

While using double quotes for query you can user single quotes too like this or if you prefer the way you used replace the below one

```
$query = "SELECT course from surprise WHERE diff_lvl = '".$level."' AND tot_days = '".$time_day."' AND tot_time = '".$time_tot."'";
```

Notice the changes in single quote and double qoute

Comment: How can I print the $query value I'm getting? I tried using echo as, echo "my value is $query"; but it is not printing. Any suggestion?

Comment: you mean printing result of query?